# Assignment of a structure that has a member std::map

Tags: c++, stl

In this piece of code below, I am having `std::map` in a structure. And I am then just assigning an instance of the structure to other. Note that the structure doesn't have assignment operator. In this case shall I expect assignment operator of map would be called or compiler just shallow copies memory contains of structures ?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct vectstruct
    {
        std::map<int, double> mymap;
    };
    vectstruct vs1, vs2;
    vs1.mymap[7] = 54.321;
    vs2 = vs1; // Should call assignment operator of map vs2.mymap
    vs1.mymap[7] = 65.432;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this with Microsft Visual Studio and at the end of program I see value of `vs2.mymap[7]` remains `54.321` as expected. But I like to know is it correct by C++ standards or do I need to write assignment operator of `vectstruct` wherein I explicitly would invoke assignment operator of map?

Comment: In general, do not write copy constructors or assignment operators if all data member behave well (as in this case). You only need these when you manage a member (eg.: pointer) (See: rule of none, rule of three, rule of five (C++11))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of style, you should declare and define your types outside of `main`.

That said, if you do not provide a copy assignment operator, the compiler will implicitly create* one for you and that implicit one will just do an element-wise copy assignment. In this case, the implicit one will look something like:

```
vectstruct& operator=(const vectstruct& rhs) {
    mymap = rhs.mymap;
    return *this;
}
```

For `std::map`, assignment does full copy, it doesn't take a reference, so at the end of your code you should expect:

```
vs2.mymap[7] == 54.321 // to the extent that equality of doubles is a thing
vs1.mymap[7] == 65.432
```

*There are cases when the compiler *cannot* create an implicit assignment operator which basically boil down to your object having a noncopyable member. For instance, a reference, or a `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

The default `operator=` will perform a member-by-member copy, which is what you expect. I. e. it will invoke `operator=` for every data member of your struct. And `std::map`, in turn, implements `operator=`, so everything will work like charm. No need to bloat your code by writing the same operator yourself.